# Java- Sending email from jsp page

Tags: java, email

I have a simple JSP page on my web application that looks like below:

[image]

There's a button below for user to hit send after entering the recipient email,subject and content of course.

I want to implement a feature that allows user to send email to outsiders.What comes into my mind is to use Java Mail API with the use of SMTP.

So,in my backend code, I wrote a function that goes like below:

```
public String sendEmail(ArrayList mediaList, String authRequired, String TLSEnabled, String SSLEnabled, String smtpHost, String senderAddress, String portNumber, String user, String password,
                            String msgSubject, String msgContent,
                            ArrayList toRecipientAdd, ArrayList ccRecipientAdd, ArrayList bccRecipientAdd) {
        try {

            final String SenderAddress = senderAddress;
            final String Username = user;
            final String Password = password;


            System.out.println("Please Wait, sending email...");

            if (toRecipientAdd.size() == 0) {
                System.out.println("NO USER FOUND IN TORECIPIENT ADDRESS.");
                return "NO USER FOUND IN TORECIPIENT ADDRESS.";
            }

            if (msgSubject.equals("")) {
                System.out.println("MESSAGE SUBJECT NOT FOUND.");
                return "MESSAGE SUBJECT NOT FOUND.";
            }

            if (msgContent.equals("")) {
                System.out.println("MESSAGE CONTENT NOT FOUND.");
                return "MESSAGE CONTENT NOT FOUND.";
            }



            /*Setup mail server */

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", authRequired);
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", portNumber);
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", TLSEnabled);
            props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", SSLEnabled);

            String auth_enable = authRequired;
            final String username = user;
            final String upassword = password;

            System.out.println("mail.smtp.host : " + smtpHost + " mail.smtp.port : " + portNumber);

            // Get session
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

            if(Boolean.parseBoolean(auth_enable)){
                session = Session.getInstance(props,
                        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {

                            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, upassword);
                            }
                        });
            }

            session.setDebug(true);



            // Define message
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            InternetAddress senderInetAddress = null;
            try {
                senderInetAddress = new InternetAddress(senderAddress);
            } catch (AddressException addressException) {
                addressException.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Set From Sender Address
            message.setFrom(senderInetAddress);

            // TO Recipient
            Iterator itr = toRecipientAdd.iterator();
            while (itr.hasNext()) {
                String receiverAddr = (String) itr.next();

                System.out.println("receiverAddr : " + receiverAddr);

                InternetAddress receiverInetAddress;
                try {
                    receiverInetAddress = new InternetAddress(receiverAddr);
                } catch (AddressException addressException) {
                    addressException.printStackTrace();
                    continue;
                }
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, receiverInetAddress);
            }

            // CC Recipient
            Iterator i = ccRecipientAdd.iterator();
            while (i.hasNext()) {
                String ccAddr = (String) i.next();
                InternetAddress ccInetAddress = null;
                try {
                    ccInetAddress = new InternetAddress(ccAddr);
                } catch (AddressException addressException) {
                    addressException.printStackTrace();
                    continue;
                }
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, ccInetAddress);
            }

            // BCC Recipient
            Iterator j = bccRecipientAdd.iterator();
            while (j.hasNext()) {
                String bccAddr = (String) j.next();
                InternetAddress bccInetAddress = null;
                try {
                    bccInetAddress = new InternetAddress(bccAddr);
                } catch (AddressException addressException) {
                    addressException.printStackTrace();
                    continue;
                }
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.BCC, bccInetAddress);
            }


            message.setSubject(msgSubject);

            Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
            MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            htmlPart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
            htmlPart.setContent(msgContent, "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
            htmlPart.setDisposition(javax.mail.Part.INLINE);
            mp.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

            Iterator mediaIter = mediaList.iterator();
            while(mediaIter.hasNext()){
                Fmedia fmedia = (Fmedia) mediaIter.next();
                DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(fmedia.getFfulpath() + "/" + fmedia.getFgname());

                MimeBodyPart imagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
                imagePart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));

                // assign a cid to the image
                imagePart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
                imagePart.addHeader("Content-ID", "<img" + fmedia.getNodeid() + ">");
                imagePart.setDisposition(javax.mail.Part.INLINE);

                mp.addBodyPart(imagePart);
            }

            message.setContent(mp);

            System.out.println("Sending.... ");

            // Send the message
            try{

                Transport.send(message, message.getAllRecipients());
                System.out.println("Message sent.");

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Exception " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return "";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
```

However,I am still unfamiliar with SMTP in Java and do not know what are the values that should be specified in the `props` and also since I am not hardcoding the `Mimemessage`, I need to get the values from the JSP page as shown above.

Would that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

in props you have set some parameters like ,

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
```

if you need further clarification please refer below sample code,

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMailSSL {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
        new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("username","password");
            }
        });

    try {

        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@no-spam.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("to@no-spam.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," +
                "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

}

Further you can pass any parameters to the sendEmail method and use those values on the code.

Comment: But this does not answer my question. I am asking how does one pass values from JSP to message?

Comment: thats what I have mentined on the last , if you are using a post method or just passing the values as query parameters just retrieve them inside the servlet class , and assign them to viriables and then simply you can use it inside the code

Comment: what about the sender email? Does it take the value of default?

Comment: No its , not , you have set it , you have to set it as below,

message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@no-spam.com")); // this means the sender address

Comment: I see. So the recipient will receive the email from sender "from@no-spam.com" right?

Comment: Also, from other resources, they also use `props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");`  and remove the other properties, is that okay?

Comment: Yes receiver will see it like that, that is ok if you are not using authentication to send an email, but the thing is if you are not using authentication your email might appeat on the spam box instead of inbox of the receiver